# Setting Mail app rules when using gmail account AND iCloud account

Tags: ipad, icloud, mail.app, gmail, mail-rules

I'm having a problem. I recently subscribed to a *daily newsletter* of the MIT. Added to that I have some other newletters from news websites.

Resulting in an average of 10-20 Mail messages per day. I want to set up mail rules for Mail on iPad.

I have a quite specific account configuration on Mail, I have one gmail account which is the one concerned with the newletters and one iCloud one on which I get an email every 3 years (not really but I got about 1-2 emails since 2019).

I have tried **going to gmail.com** to add rules for incoming emails, but, ***it doesn't work***, I added the rules, seemed alright, it showed the emails in question when searching for what I wanted (ex. Searching for subject containing "MIT", it shows all the newletter emails I have received including the most recent ones). But it doesn't seem to work at all, not even on the gmail.com website.

I have also tried **modifying Mail rules on icloud.com**, following tutorials I've found. I don't know if this worked because I haven't received emails on iCloud for a year or so. And I don't think setting Mail rules for iCloud will be useful since I haven't subscribed to newsletters on it.

That's quite a big problem because I need to spend time each day to sort manually all the newsletters in separate mailboxes and if I don't do this, the emails will accumulate and saturate my inbox and I will need to spend a lot of time searching for important emails. I read my newsletters about every weekend but haven't found a way to send all of them directly on Saturday for example (setting up in websites that are originating newsletters), but that's not the problem.

My question : **How to set Mail rules for Mail app (iPad) when connected to two accounts, one gmail receiving tons of newsletters and one iCloud receiving very few emails?**

*Note: I am on iPad 6th generation running iPadOS 16.2*

**Edit** : The gmail rules I've set (all of them are using the same parameters except the one for wordoftheday@vocabulary.com which is using the sender) :

[image: all rules]

When clicking on "edit" for "MIT" :

[image: parameter description]

(Click on the images to open fullscreen (better resolution))

Comment: Rules created in gmail.com work well (better than any Apple app). It is what I use. Rules in iCloud.com work correctly, but are very limited compared with gmail.

Comment: @Gilby I have already tried setting gmail rules but they do not apply...

Comment: @JBallin Yes, added that as an edit to the question. :) https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/457616/3

Comment: @JBallin Better now? :)

Comment: @JBallin I fixed the images but I thought you were able to click on them to open fullsize on imgur.com . That works for me at least.

Comment: @JBallin I want to move them to a specific inbox

Comment: @JBallin Also, if you look at the menu on the left, at the bottom, it shows that the inboxed are also labels. The Gmail/MIT ... as well as the others are in the category label but they still contain emails (the ones I've added manually).

Comment: A labels view will pull in all emails that contain the label, regardless of whether they are in the inbox. What you likely want to do is both apply a label AND skip inbox. If you still have questions about gmail itself, I would suggest asking a question on https://superuser.com/.

Comment: @JBallin Thanks, this works! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Gmail filters only "Apply label", you should also "Skip the inbox".